# Определить энтропию источника

Tags: информатика, информация

Определить энтропию источника информации A , передающего сообщения A(i), i=1..4   Вероятность сообщений равна: p1=0,23 , p2=0,27 , p3=0,16 , p4=0,34.

Известно, что в сообщении источника 100 символов. 
Определить, сколько символов потребуется для передачи этой информации при использовании безызбыточного алфавита той же размерности

Нашел для данной задачи энтропию по формуле Шеннона H(A) = - сумма (p(i)log2(pi)) , дальше скорее всего нужно применять формулу Хартли : N = log2(I) , но не пойму каким образом, можете подсказать идею ?

Comment: Предоставляйте задания с минимально воспроизводимым примером, вашими наработками, что уже сделали и на чём остановились. Таким образом мы сможем быстрее вам помочь.